# Selecting batches of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `widget_events` that records `event_what` events occurring to
widget `widget_id` on date `event_when`.  It's possible for the same event to
occur multiple times to the same widget on the same day.  For this reason,
column `event_id` is used as primary key to distinguish such rows.  Here is
the table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE widget_events
(
event_id    int4 UNIQUE NOT NULL,
event_when  date NOT NULL,
event_what  text NOT NULL,
widget_id   int4 REFERENCES widgets (widget_id) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
);
```

The client application processes events in batches, where each batch consists
of all events for one widget on one date.  However, the application has no
previous knowledge of which widgets and dates are stored in `widget_events`.

One possible solution is to start by selecting one random row from 
`widget_events` (using SQL's `LIMIT`), and then do another query for all
rows with the same `widget_id` and `widget_when`.  After this batch is
processed, those rows can be deleted from `widget_events`, and we go back
to the first step.  The algorithm stops when the first step reports that
there is no more random row to return.

My question is whether there is a faster, more elegant way to do this.
Is it possible in SQL (in particular the SQL understood by PostgreSQL) 
to return each distinct batch in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select distinct batches:

```
select  distinct event_when
,       event_what
from    widget_events
```

Or you could pick up a single batch in one query, like:

```
select  batch.*
from    widget_events batch
join    (
        select  event_when
        ,       event_what
        from    widget_events
        limit   1
        ) filter
on      filter.event_when = batch.event_when
        and filter.event_what = batch.event_what
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In the end, I went for the solution you described first: return all distinct batches, and then let the client request all data for each batch one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just return the rows, ordered by event_when:

```
select *
from widget_events we
order by event_when, event_what, event_id
```

I threw in event_what as well, so all similar events will be on consecutive rows.

Your logic can then just look for when the date changes to determine whether something is the last event.  You could even put this into the select, if you wanted:

```
select *,
       (case when lag(event_when) over (partition by event_id) < event_when then 1
             else 0
        end) as isFirst,
       (case when lead(event_when) over (partition by event_id) < event_when then 1
             else 0
        end) as isLast
from widget_events we
order by event_when, event_what, event_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The problem with this approach is that all data would be returned to the client in a single call, and it may be too much to keep in memory.

Comment: @JonSmark . . . How are you reading the data?  Typically, this would be in a loop and you would read until isLast = 1, and then continue.